# How to Render Different Objects in Same Rabl File

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I would like to render different Objects in the same RABL file. How can I render this kind of JSON?

**Here is the controller:**

```
def index
  @participations = User.find_by(id_number: params[:tc]).participations
  @examinations = Examination.all
end
```

**And I want this JSON output =>**

```
participations: (will loop participations)
  {
    name: (participation.examination.name)
    shortname: (participation.examination.short_name)
    first_name: (participation.user.first_name)
  }

examinations: (will loop @examinations)
  {
    name: (Examination.name)
    shortname: (Examination.short_name)
    first_name: (User.find_by(id_number: params[:tc]).first_name)
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you want to output json? if Yes then `render json: {participations: @participations, examinations: @examinations, status: :ok`}, get the object select the element and loop

Comment: I'm not rendering anything on the controller. I have a RABL file and that does the whole thing.

Comment: Check out this: https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/319

Comment: Not the thing that I'm looking for.